# How to set many events for one function

Tags: c#, textbox, textchanged

i have in my form this components:

```
textbox1
textbox2
textbox3
textbox4

button1
```

and one function:

```
private void checkStatusTextBoxes()
{
   button1.Enabled = ( (textbox1.Text.Length != 0) && (textbox2.Text.Length != 0) && (textbox3.Text.Lenght != 0) && (textbox4.Text.Length !=0));
}
```

and I want to check it when changes text in textboxes, here you go:

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  checkStatusTextBoxes();
}
```

I would not to repeat it for each textbox, i would to add in one event (?). How I can do it?

Comment: Attach `textbox1_TextChanged` event handler for all of them. This is easy.

Answer (score 2):

For each TextBox on the form...

1. Right-click on the TextBox
2. Select Properties
3. Click on the lightning bolt to get the list of events
4. Go to TextChanged
5. Click the dropdown arrow
6. Select `textbox1_TextChanged` as the event handler

I'd recommend changing the name of the event handler though so it's clear it handles all the TextChanged events instead of just the one for textbox1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same  event handler for all of them:

```
textbox1.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
textbox2.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
textbox3.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
textbox4.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the same handler to your textboxes for example:

```
textbox1.TextChanged += TextChanged;
textbox2.TextChanged += TextChanged;
textbox3.TextChanged += TextChanged;
textbox4.TextChanged += TextChanged;

private void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkStatusTextBoxes();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same event handler:

```
textbox1.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
textbox2.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
textbox3.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
textbox4.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;

private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  checkStatusTextBoxes();
}
```